# Google App Script keeps reading an old value from a sheets cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a script that checks for FOO in any cell of column A, and where there's a match, it will write BAR in the matching row of column B.

If I put FOO in A1, it puts BAR in B1, excellent. But if I remove or type something else into A1, and delete BAR from B1, a few seconds later it automatically puts BAR in B1 again.

I've tried different triggers, such as On edit, On change, On open, but haven't had any luck.

I guess there's a cache going on with the cell values, but I wonder is there a way to force it to read the actual latest values from the cells? To discard any cache it has?

```
function containsText(cellValue, searchText) {
  return cellValue.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
}

function updateCellValue() {
  const sheetName = "MySheet";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (!sheet) {
    Logger.log(`Sheet ${sheetName} not found!`);
    return;
  }

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + lastRow);
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
 
  for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    var cellValue = dataValues[i][0];
    if (containsText(cellValue, "FOO")) {
      sheet.getRange("B" + (i + 1)).setValue("BAR");
    }
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Comment: For future users, both answers provided do the job :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### RECOMMENDATION

**[Updated]**

The following script should be able to detect any instances of "FOO" on your spreadsheet, and should apply "BAR" right beside it. **You can check this for your reference:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
      const sheetName = "MySheet";
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
      if (!sheet) {
        Logger.log(`Sheet ${sheetName} not found!`);
        return;
      }
    
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1,1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
      var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
    
      for( i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i ++){    
        if (dataValues[i][0] == "FOO"){      
          sheet.getRange(i+1,2,1,1).setValue("BAR");   
        }
        else{
          sheet.getRange(i+1,2,1,1).clear();
        }      
      }
    
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, hmm it's close, but it seems when you copy several rows at once (e.g. from an online banking statement into the sheet), it puts BAR on the first row if it's in any of the pasted rows.

For example pasting this into A1 & A2:

MOO
FOO

Then BAR will appear in B1

Comment: Hi! I just updated my script and it should take into account the instances of copy-pasted answers and should populate "BAR" right beside "FOO". I also saw on another comment that you want the "BAR" to be deleted if "FOO" gets deleted or changed to another string, so the script should be able to handle that as well.

Comment: Fantastic thank you!! And even without the clear I see it doesn't keep putting BAR there even when I remove the FOO. I'll just try applying this to my actual non-foobar sheet but it seems like this will be perfect.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to know that my answer works with your case. Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the accept button on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that their problem can also be solved with this.

Comment: Thanks again, both answers in here seem to work great :)

Answer (score 2):

***[UPDATED]***

Perhaps you can try this via `match` *(ref: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)* in your `containsText` function.

This method will match any cell that will contain the `searchText` value.

> *E.g. If a cell contains `MOO FOO` and `searchText` is **FOO**, it should still return as `true`*.

```
function containsText(cellValue, searchText) {
  return cellValue && cellValue[0] && cellValue[0].match(searchText);
}

function updateCellValue() {
  const sheetName = "MySheet";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (!sheet) {
    Logger.log(`Sheet ${sheetName} not found!`);
    return;
  }

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + lastRow);
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();

  //Simplified your looping using 'forEach' method
  dataValues.forEach((cell, row) => containsText(cell, "FOO") && sheet.getRange("B" + (row + 1)).setValue("BAR"));

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Comment: @LostBoyNZ I hope this helps. If you have questions, just let me know.

Comment: Thank you :)

I seem to be having a different issue now where the includes doesn't work. So strange though because you're right the includes function should be perfect.

I added a toast and it shows the FOO returns true, but MOO FOO returns false. So confusing :/

Comment: Let me check on it. Are you running your script in a trigger by any chance?

Comment: Thanks, using an 'On edit' trigger yes

Comment: Got it. Working on it.

Comment: Thanks for waiting. I have updated my answer. Upon further testing, it seems you need a more flexible method in your use case. Instead of using `includes` you could use `match`.

Comment: Hoping I was able to help. If this answer addresses your question, you may consider clicking the 'accept' button or up-voting this answer. This will help other members who are trying to achieve the same thing to quickly find your question. Thank you!

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you!! Both your code and Mic Test's code solve the problem. Hopefully these help future users with the problem too. Thank you again, I've added the code to my sheet now